# Modal footer not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In the below code the modal footer is not being displayed. Its displaying the close button of footer but its outside the modal. No idea why is it happening. Modal body is displaying but not modal footer and also an extra line is being displayed after modal title. Can anybody help me?

```
     echo "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-  
     target='#myModal' style='margin-top:230px;margin-  
      left:10px;'>Appointment</button>";

      echo "<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog'   
      aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
      echo "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
      echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
      echo "<div class='modal-header'>";
      echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-  
      hidden='true'>&times;</button>";
      echo "<h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Book    
      Appointment</h4>";

       echo "</div>";
       echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
       echo "<div class='col-md-8'>";
       echo "<div class='row'>";
       echo "<label for='idTourDateDetails'>Date and Time</label>";
       echo "<div class='form-group'>";
       echo "<div class='input-group'>";
       echo "<input type='text' name='idTourDateDetails' id='idTourD  
       ateDetails' readonly='readonly' class='form-control clsDatePicker'> 
      <span class='input-group-addon'><i id='calIconTourDateDetails' 
      class='glyphicon glyphicon-th'></i></span>";

      echo "</div>";

        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
         echo "</div>";

       echo "<div class='modal-footer'>";
       echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-
       dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";
       echo "</div>";
       echo "</div>";
       echo "</div>";
       echo "</div>";           
       echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Check the closing tags of each elements. You might me missing one.

Comment: missing or extra? I feel like I have an extra but when I remove one div tag the display is disturbed.

Comment: Rechekd it and there is no missing tags neither extra. But still footer not working

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it (div tag issue)

```css
#myModal{
  border:solid black;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-  
     target='#myModal' style='margin-top:230px;margin-  
      left:10px;'>Appointment</button>
<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog'   
      aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
<div class='modal-dialog'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-  
      hidden='true'>&times;</button>
      <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Book    
      Appointment</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <div class='col-md-8'>
        <div class='row'>
          <label for='idTourDateDetails'>Date and Time</label>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <div class='input-group'>
              <input type='text' name='idTourDateDetails' id='idTourD  
       ateDetails' readonly='readonly' class='form-control clsDatePicker'> 
              <span class='input-group-addon'><i id='calIconTourDateDetails' 
      class='glyphicon glyphicon-th'></i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-footer'>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-
       dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what i expected. I want a footer not a border.

Comment: I put a border test see if footer in modal div..my apologies if i didn't reach your expectation